# How to Screenshot a Website Element without Collapsible Division using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, screenshot

I want to screenshot just the US hot pots map in https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html but the collapsible division at the very bottom (that says Thanks for reading the Times) keeps coming with the screenshot:
[image]

How can I exclude that?

Also ideally the New York Time banner at the top would be cropped out. I used Pillow's Image.crop() to crop from the first image captured but wonder if there is a more convenient/elegant way to achieve that. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Here's my code:

```py
from Screenshot import Screenshot
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image 

ob = Screenshot.Screenshot()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.page_load_strategy = 'none'
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html"
driver.get(url)

class_name = "mapboxgl-canvas"
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
element.screenshot('{}.png'.format(class_name))
location = element.location
size = element.size 
print(class_name, 'location:', location, 'size:', size, '\n')

location = element.location 
size = element.size 
x = location['x'] 
# y = location['y'] 
y = 30
w = x + size['width'] 
h = y + size['height'] 
# x = 0; y = 10; w = 950; h = 600
fullImg = Image.open("mapboxgl-canvas.png") 
cropImg = fullImg.crop((x, y, w, h))
cropImg.save('cropImage.png') 

driver.close()

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

After tons of trials and errors, finally I got my code to work. The key is to suppress the expandable dock and re-position the capturing window in js.
Attached is the map with top banner and bottom mapbox logo cropped out.[image]

```py
import platform
from Screenshot import Screenshot
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions 
import numpy as np

#--------------------------------     Part 1 Take a Screenshot of the Map    -----------------------------------
#Set up Chrome driver
options = ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = True 
options.add_argument('--page_load_strategy = none') #suppress browser window

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ('/usr/local/bin/' if platform.system() == 'Linux' else '' + 'chromedriver') 
                          , options=options)
# driver.get_window_rect()
_ = driver.set_window_rect(x=0, y=50, width=1000, height=1000)
# driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='145%'")

#Load the website to capture screenshot
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html"
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("""window.scrollTo(0, 2071); 
                        var element = document.querySelector('[data-testid="expanded-dock"]');
                        element.style.visibility = 'collapse';
                        element.style.height = '0px';""") #Suppress the randomly pop-out expandable dock at the bottom which messes up the screenshot window


#Identify the element to screenshot, which is the hot spots map
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Can't use class_name = "mapboxgl-canary",'multi-map', "map-wrap", "mapboxgl-interactive"
#These class_names are the same as "mapboxgl-canvas":  "aspect-ratio-outer", "aspect-ratio-inner", "map", "mapboxgl-map"
#Using ID = "maps" works too, just y location is different. Stick to class_name = "mapboxgl-canvas"
# tag = "maps"
# element = driver.find_element(By.ID, tag)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tag = "mapboxgl-canvas"
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, tag)
img_path = '{}.png'.format(tag)
_ = element.screenshot(img_path)

#Check map location and size for window.scrollTo coordinates
location = element.location
size = element.size 
print(tag, 'location:', location, 'size:', size, '\n')
# Make sure window.scrollTo = y location = 2382 and height and width stay at 643 and 919 when configuring set_window_rect()
# mapboxgl-canvas location: {'x': 30, 'y': 2382} size: {'height': 643, 'width': 919}

#Crop image to remove unwanted pixels
# x = location['x'] 
# y = location['y'] 
x=0; y=30 #Start from a lower position to crop the top banner 
w = x + size['width'] 
h = y + size['height'] - 60 #Subtract from height to remove mapbox logo at the bottom
fullImg = Image.open(img_path) 
cropImg = fullImg.crop((x, y, w, h)) #(left, upper, right, lower)-tuple
cropImg.save('cropImage.png') 
fullImg.close()
driver.close()
driver.quit()

#---------  Part 2 Mask unwanted parts of the image (top right size control, P.R. region at bottom right)   -----------
im = Image.open('cropImage.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

#Vertices of masking rectangles, one for top right size control, the other for bottom right Puerto Rico
top_left = (cropImg.width -41, 0)
bottom_right = (cropImg.width - 8, 40)
top_left2 = (cropImg.width - 100, cropImg.height - 45)
bottom_right2 = (cropImg.width - 40, cropImg.height - 15)

draw.rectangle((top_left, bottom_right), fill=(255, 255, 255))
draw.rectangle((top_left2, bottom_right2), fill=(255, 255, 255))

# Save final image
im.save('cropImage1.png')
```